# Devise Controller error: undefined local variable or method `mimes_for_respond_to'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am getting the following routing error after installing Devise

```
undefined local variable or method `mimes_for_respond_to' for DeviseController:Class
```

I have no idea how to fix this

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-11 22:56:37 -0500
  ActionController::RoutingError (undefined local variable or method `mimes_for_respond_to' for DeviseController:Class):
  devise (3.4.0) app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:13:in `<class:DeviseController>'
  devise (3.4.0) app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:444:in `load'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:444:in `block in  load_file'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:634:in     `new_constants_in'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load_file'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:343:in `require_or_load'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:481:in `load_missing_constant'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
  devise (3.4.0) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:444:in `load'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:444:in `block in  load_file'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:634:in `new_constants_in'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load_file'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:343:in `require_or_load'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:481:in `load_missing_constant'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:263:in `const_get'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:263:in `block in constantize'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:553:in `get'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:584:in `constantize'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:68:in `controller_reference'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:58:in `controller'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:37:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:48:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:750:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'


 warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:257:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:558:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:645:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:83:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  web-console (2.0.0.beta4) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:18:in `middleware_call'
  web-console (2.0.0.beta4) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0.beta2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0.beta2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0.beta2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:103:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0.beta2) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0.beta2) lib/rails/application.rb:161:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/lint.rb:49:in `_call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/lint.rb:37:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/showexceptions.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:33:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/chunked.rb:54:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
  /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in 

`block in start_thread'
```

Thank you for suggesting I put in the full trace. I've tried changing the namespace form ActionController::Base to ActionController::API and included the two modules but it has not worked.

I updated my gem file by taking out the betaversion's and ran bundle update then bundle install. Unfortunately,now I am getting  an error when trying to launch the server...

```
/Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-    4.1.8/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in     `method_missing'/Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/orm_adapter-    0.5.0/lib/orm_adapter/adapters/active_record.rb:81: warning: already initialized constant     ActiveRecord::Base::OrmAdapter
/Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/orm_adapter-    0.5.0/lib/orm_adapter/adapters/active_record.rb:81: warning: previous definition of     OrmAdapter was here
: undefined method `raise_in_transactional_callbacks=' for #<Class:0x0000010625bcf8> (NoMethodError)
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:110:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:109:in `each'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:109:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:326:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/orm/active_record.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/projects/ecommerce/stripe_tutorial/config/initializers/devise.rb:22:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise.rb:293:in `setup'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/projects/ecommerce/stripe_tutorial/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in `block in load_config_initializer'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:647:in `load_config_initializer'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:418:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:417:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `call'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/projects/ecommerce/stripe_tutorial/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/projects/ecommerce/stripe_tutorial/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/projects/ecommerce/stripe_tutorial/config.ru:in `new'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/projects/ecommerce/stripe_tutorial/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:130:in `log_to_stdout'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:67:in `start'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/projects/ecommerce/stripe_tutorial/bin/rails:8:in `require'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/projects/ecommerce/stripe_tutorial/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.2.0/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/projects/ecommerce/stripe_tutorial/bin/spring:16:in `require'
from /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/projects/ecommerce/stripe_tutorial/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I ran rake rails:update and now I am seeing this:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-11 23:46:40 -0500
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
 Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (14.1ms)
```

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 48ms

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `registration_path' for #<#    <Class:0x00000106aa4838>:0x00000106da2648>):
1: <h2>Sign up</h2>
2: 
3: <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
4:   <%= devise_error_messages! %>
5: 
6:   <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:3:in     `_app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb__851977968835860680_2203413860'


  Rendered /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/web-console-    2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_source.erb (14.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (5.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (47.1ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my server and now everything seems to be OK

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Using Rails 4.1.8 or 4.2 beta? If the answer was to use Rails 4.1, then that's the answer (this will help people with similar problems ending up here).

Comment: I am currently running 4.1.8